# How to set VSCODE to increment file name when making a copy?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

VSCode for mac Version 1.36.1, if that's relevant.

When I select a file and ⌘+C / ⌘+V, the new file name used to be incremented, for example file1.txt => file2.txt. But now somehow it changed. It will be file1.txt => file1 copy.txt.

I want to get the previous behavior back, or even better, to customize how the copied file should be renamed.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was intentionally [changed in VS Code 1.36](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_copy-paste-filename-incrementor-change).

In VS Code 1.38, a new setting `"explorer.incrementalNaming": "smart"` was [added](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76752) that reverts to the old incremental file naming behavior

Comment: Thank you. That's too bad. I can't think of any use case that I will want a copy-pasted file to be named as filename + " copy".

Comment: Thank you, Matt! I missed the "smart" incremental naming.  I'm glad they provided a way to revert back to this previous behavior.